# How to run spark job in ADF?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I created a spark job with parameters and attached an interactive cluster to it in Azure Databricks. I have a pipeline in Azure data factory using a notebook activity. When i created How a linked service, it is pointing to my interactive cluster. How do I use ADF to run pipeline using the job I creates in databricks?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the databricks job with Notebook activity in ADF. But as far as I know, the Notebook activity is used for only to ***create and execute the new databricks job*** for the notebook.

> I created a spark job with parameters

So, you have already created a databricks job.

To execute the ***existing job of databricks in ADF***, you can use other ADF activities and Databricks jobs API.

Please go through this [Microsoft Official blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/leverage-azure-databricks-jobs-orchestration-from-azure-data/ba-p/3123862) by **Leo Furlong** and **ClintonWFord** which has step by step explanation to run a databricks job in ADF involving the activities like ***web activity for Run now API and wait actvity***.

With this approach you can execute whichever job you want by passing the ***JobId*** and ***Databricks workspace Id*** in pipeline parameters as shown in the above link.

If you want to execute multiple jobs in ADF you can try this [approach](https://medium.com/@ivangomezarnedo/how-to-orchestrate-databricks-jobs-from-azure-data-factory-using-databricks-rest-api-4d5e8c577581) by **Iván Gómez Arnedo**.

Comment: Thank you for this. This approach works.